# Red, dotted lines around links

Tags: google-chrome, google-developers-console

It's probably trivial but I'm not sure how do I get rid of it.

[image: how it looks]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question doesn't contain enough information. Also, "im" isn't a word in English.

Answer (score 1):

These are the result of some addOns on your computer. These are used by the developers to check the elements in their development phase. Please refer to your installed addOns and disable/ uninstall them one by one. And point out which one was triggering this.
This is not a problem but an unwanted feature for you apparently.